# Testing an function that calculates age from dob

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, momentjs

I have a simple function in Javascript;

```
  export default function getPupilAge(dob) {
  let a = moment();
  let b = moment(dob);
  return a.diff(b, 'months');
};
```

I am trying to write tests (I am using AVA).

I would like to write a test that says 'given a date returns 23 months' but the  `let a = moment();` is always today's date so the returned number of months will change over time.

How do I write this test, or refactor my function to allow testability?

Comment: what about it do you think is not testable as written?  also are you using a testing framework like jasemine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function seems to calculate age in months (it uses `diff` from `moment()` with `'months'` parameter), so you can pass `moment().subtract(23, 'month');` that is the current date minus 23 months (see [`subtract`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) docs). In this case `getPupilAge` will always be `23`.

Here a live example:

```js
function getPupilAge(dob) {
  let a = moment();
  let b = moment(dob);
  return a.diff(b, 'months');
};

let dob = moment().subtract(23, 'month');
console.log(getPupilAge(dob));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **sinon** to fake the date and time.
e.g.

```
import test from 'ava';
import sinon from 'sinon';

function getPupilAge(dob) {
  let a = moment(); // here the date will be 2016-12-01T06:00:00.000Z
  let b = moment(dob); //here the date will be what you have specified in dob
  return a.diff(b, 'months');
}

test('fake dates', t => {
    sinon.useFakeTimers(new Date(2016,11,1).getTime());

    const result = getPupilAge("20170620");

    t.is(result,6) //example


});
```

In your function when you call **moment()** you will get the fake date.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do `let day = moment("1995-12-25");`